# Calculate how long it took to close a card

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

We would like to calculate how long it takes to close an issue. One approach would be to subtract the resolution date from the created date. The problem with this approach is that an issue may wait in "backlog" for weeks before it is actually started.

Is there any way to access when an issue entered the "Work In Progress" state or any other status for that matter? This way we can subtract this status change date from the resolved date. Being able to query state changes or transitions of the card from one state to another would be helpful.

We are writing data extraction jobs that send JQL queries and retrieve JSON back. We are willing to send other queries to extract other data that would allow us to calculate the actual time spent on the issues from the first query.

For example, for all issues closed in the last 7 days, we want to calculate how much time was spent on those cards. For us, that would be the time it entered WIP to the time it was resolved.

Not all cards have a worklog, so that approach did not work for us.

How can we calculate the time an issue entered Work In Progress and worked to resolution?

Answer (score 0):

The approach we implemented is calling the REST API using `expand=changelog` to return all the change items for the issue.  We then extract the status change items and use the created date for the change items that contain the state transition we need.

This results in larger JSON results, but we extract only the change items we want.